# Problem with Video drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have the following problem with my computer. Мy video card is quite old and I have great trouble finding drivers for it:

- Acer Aspire 5745G-333G32 Mn
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-330M Processor ( 2.13 GHz, 3MB)
- HDD: 320 GB SATA (5400 rpm)
- Graphics card : Nvidia GeForce G 310M 512MB

Yesterday I decided to install driver version 340.93 but without success and had to reinstall again. Could someone tell me, what drivers are best for me and I will not have a problem after their installation because then I always have again reinstall.

[image: driver manager screenshot]

Comment: How did you install the drivers?

Comment: I'm new use Ubuntu :)

Tagged > Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.93 > Apple Changes (And then black screen)

Comment: Are you connected to internet? Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`. Are there any errors? What is Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there something got messed up when you tried to install the NVIDIA 340.93 GPU drivers.

Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the current stable NVIDIA drivers supporting your NVIDIA 310M GPU by executing :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

Comment: @Bofmin : I am glad that it worked for you ! - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)